# Constructor injection and arrays with Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I would like to understand whether there is a clean way to use constructor injection with arrays in spring-boot (1.3.5.RELEASE).

I've created this simple app that better explains my question:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static class Car { }

    @Bean
    public Car[] cars() {
        return IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(i -> new Car()).toArray(Car[]::new);
    }

    @Component
    private static class Road implements CommandLineRunner {

        private final Car[] cars;

        @Autowired
        public Road(Car[] cars) {
            this.cars = cars;
        }

//      @Resource
//      private Car[] cars;

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cars));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I understand that @Autowired works by type, so the reason why the previous application does not work is because when the Car[] has to be injected, Spring first tries to find all Car beans but, since there is no Car bean, the following exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'application.Road' defined in file [/spring-array-injection/target/classes/com/stackoverflow/Application$Road.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.stackoverflow.Application$Car[]]: No qualifying bean of type [com.stackoverflow.Application$Car] found for dependency [array of com.stackoverflow.Application$Car]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.stackoverflow.Application$Car] found for dependency [array of com.stackoverflow.Application$Car]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.stackoverflow.Application.main(Application.java:44) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.stackoverflow.Application$Car] found for dependency [array of com.stackoverflow.Application$Car]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I also understand that if I replace the constructor injection with field injection + @Resource everything works because the array is injected by name instead of type.

So, am I missing something or is it a real spring limitation (i.e. it is currently not possible to use constructor injection with arrays/lists of object in spring)?

#### UPDATE 1

Wow, I thought this question had a shorter life but the case is not solved yet. I will post the two (ugly) workarounds I've tested so far:

1. A wrapper around the array is injected instead of the plain array:

   ```
   package com.stackoverflow.workaround.arrayholder;

   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.stream.IntStream;

   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application {

       private static class ArrayHolder<T> {

           private final T array;

           public ArrayHolder(T array) {
               this.array = array;
           }

           public T getArray() {
               return array;
           }

       }

       private static class Car { }

       @Bean
       public ArrayHolder<Car[]> cars() {
           return new ArrayHolder<>(IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(i -> new Car()).toArray(Car[]::new));
       }

       @Component
       private static class Road implements CommandLineRunner {

           private final Car[] cars;

           @Autowired
           public Road(ArrayHolder<Car[]> cars) {
               this.cars = cars.getArray();
           }

           @Override
           public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
               System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cars));
           }

       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       }

   }
   ```
2. The beans are dynamically created and registered using the BeanFactoryPostProcessor:

   ```
   package com.stackoverflow.workaround.dynamicregistration;

   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
   import java.util.stream.IntStream;

   import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
   import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

       private static class Car { }

       @Override
       public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
           AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
           IntStream.range(0, 10)
               .mapToObj(i -> new Car())
               .forEach(car -> beanFactory.registerSingleton(String.valueOf(atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()), car));
       }

       @Component
       private static class Road implements CommandLineRunner {

           private final Car[] cars;

           @Autowired
           public Road(Car[] cars) {
               this.cars = cars;
           }

           @Override
           public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
               System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cars));
           }

       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       }

   }
   ```

#### Update 2

It turns out that constructor injection of arrays, collections and maps will be possible starting from Spring 4.3 (see [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14332)).

Comment: Have you tried using @Qualifier to autowire by name instead in the constructor?

Comment: Unless I made some mistake, yes. I've added @Qualifier("cars") to the constructor parameter of Road. I've also tried changing the bean name with @Bean(name = "carz") and then adding @Qualifier("carz") to the constructor parameter of Road. Same result.

Comment: I don't know how to get Spring to inject an array bean, as opposed to an array of beans, but you could always wrap the array in another object (bean) and provide a getCars() method.  It's indirect and more of a pain but should work.

Comment: I thought about that too but I'm still hoping it's my mistake. In another project I'm using HK2 and there is no such limitation.

Comment: Can't you use List? That works for sure

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that too but, as far as I know, the principle for injecting arrays and lists is the same: spring looks for bean of the type specified by the container. So, it doesn't work either.

Comment: As stated in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers): "As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through `@Autowired`, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use `@Resource` for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name." (and arrays are treated the same way as collections, I believe)

Comment: @Roman, I can definitely accept your answer. It's not absolutely explicit but an implication of those statements is that constructor injection of arrays, collections and maps it's not possible (or, at least, this is what I understand!).

Comment: @Roman, I just opened a documentation improvement https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14332. You could mention that too in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the docs:

> **[6.9.4 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)**
>   If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not primarily use `@Autowired`, even if is technically capable of referring to a bean name through `@Qualifier` values. Instead, use the JSR-250 `@Resource` annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type being irrelevant for the matching process.
>
> As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, **beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through `@Autowired`**, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use `@Resource` for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name.
>
> `@Autowired` applies to fields, constructors, and multi-argument methods, allowing for narrowing through qualifier annotations at the parameter level. By contrast, `@Resource` is supported only for fields and bean property setter methods with a single argument. As a consequence, stick with qualifiers if your injection target is a constructor or a multi-argument method.

And arrays are treated the same way as collections:

> **[6.4.5 Autowiring collaborators](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire)**
>   With *byType* or *constructor* autowiring mode, you can wire arrays and typed-collections. In such cases *all* autowire candidates within the container that match the expected type are provided to satisfy the dependency. You can autowire strongly-typed Maps if the expected key type is `String`. An autowired Maps values will consist of all bean instances that match the expected type, and the Maps keys will contain the corresponding bean names.

> **[6.9.2 @Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)**
>   It is also possible to provide *all* beans of a particular type from the `ApplicationContext` by adding the annotation to a field or method that expects an array of that type: [...]
>   The same applies for typed collections: [...]
>   Even typed Maps can be autowired as long as the expected key type is `String`. The Map values will contain all beans of the expected type, and the keys will contain the corresponding bean names: [...]